# Font Awesome Integrity Check Error after Deploying to Heroku

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

After trying to deploy to Heroku, I get

```rb
error https://npm.fontawesome.com/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/-/fontawesome-svg-core-1.2.6.tgz: Integrity check failed for "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core" (computed integrity doesn't match our records,
```

Two days ago I deployed and nothing happened.

Rails version: 4.2;
NodeJS version: 8.10.0

Is someone aware of a fix for this? I already tried:

```sh
yarn cache clean
yarn install
yarn --update-checksums
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just became aware that Font Awesome is having problems with Integrity Checks.

You can check its status here: https://status.fortawesome.com/

[image]